# Annotation of the node of neural network:

Tags: tikz-pgf, annotations

Here is the code of the neural network representation:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}


\def\layersep{2.5cm}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
    \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
    % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
        \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,4}
        \path[yshift=0.5cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};

    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-2] (O) {};

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,4}
            \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,4}
        \path (H-\source) edge (O);

    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {$a{[1]}$};
    \node[annot,left of=hl] {$a{[0]}$};
    \node[annot,right of=hl] {$a{[2]}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want to annotate each node(to write some text inside each circle). How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}


\def\layersep{2.5cm}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
\tikzset{every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
    neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt},
    input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50},
    output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
    hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=blue!50},
    annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered}
    }

    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \y/\Txt in {1/feep,2/dunno,3/why}
    % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
        \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\y) at (0,-\y) {\Txt};

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \y/\Txt in {1/am,2/doing,3/all,4/this}
        \path[yshift=0.5cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H-\y) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {\Txt};

    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-2] (O)
    {stuff};

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,4}
            \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,4}
        \path (H-\source) edge (O);

    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {$a{[1]}$};
    \node[annot,left of=hl] {$a{[0]}$};
    \node[annot,right of=hl] {$a{[2]}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```