# Neural network Graph (one and two hidden layers)

Tags: neuralnetwork

[image]

I apologize for the question, but I have been struggling for 5 hours and I am not doing well at all. I know there are other questions in this regard, I tried to use tikz, but when I take an example from this site and try to remove / add nodes the result does not look good at all.

\begin{tikzpicture}[
shorten >=1pt,->,
draw=black!1000,
node distance=\layersep,
every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
neuron/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt},
input neuron/.style={neuron},
output neuron/.style={neuron},
hidden neuron/.style={neuron},
annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered}
]

```
% Draw the input layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
% This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
    \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

% set number of hidden layers
\newcommand\Nhidden{2}

% Draw the hidden layer nodes
\foreach \N in {1,...,\Nhidden} {
   \foreach \y in {1,...,2} {
      \path[yshift=0.5cm]
          node[hidden neuron] (H\N-\y) at (\N*\layersep,-\y cm) {};
       }
\node[annot,above of=H\N-1, node distance=1cm] (hl\N) {Hidden layer \N};
}

% Draw the output layer node
\node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H\Nhidden-3] (O) {};

% Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
% hidden layer.
\foreach \source in {1,...,3}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,2}
        \path (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);

% connect all hidden stuff
\foreach [remember=\N as \lastN (initially 1)] \N in {2,...,\Nhidden}
   \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
       \foreach \dest in {1,...,3}
           \path (H\lastN-\source) edge (H\N-\dest);

% Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
\foreach \source in {1,...,3}
    \path (H\Nhidden-\source) edge (O);

% Annotate the layers

\node[annot,left of=hl1] {Input layer};
\node[annot,right of=hl\Nhidden] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This code is for the second graph... and the result is:

[image]

Comment: Welcome back to TeX.SE! Your question could be improved if you actually show code of what you have tried and explain why the result is not what you want.

Comment: code  Published 2006-12-07 | Author: Kjell Magne Fauske-- https://texample.net/tikz/examples/neural-network/ is edited as per your requirement below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annotation of the node of neural network:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424188/annotation-of-the-node-of-neural-network)

Comment: @JeT--pray explain how the link given by you  meets the second requirement of the OP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first neural graph ---original code Published 2006-12-07 | Author: Kjell Magne Fauske-- texample.net/tikz/examples/neural-network

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\layersep{2.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
    \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
    % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
        \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
        \path[yshift=0.0cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};

    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-2] (O) {};

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,3}
            \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \path (H-\source) edge (O);

    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
    \node[annot,left of=hl] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```

**edit--the second neural graph**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\layersep{2.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
    \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
    % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
        \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};
        
        
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
% Draw the input layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,2}
% This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
\node[hidden neuron] (J-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
        \path[yshift=0.0cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (2*\layersep,-\y cm) {};
%
%    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-2] (O) {};
%
%    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
%    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,2}
            \path (I-\source) edge (J-\dest);
%

 \foreach \source in {1,...,2}
\foreach \dest in {1,...,3}
\path (J-\source) edge (H-\dest);


%    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \dest in {1,..,2}
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \path (H-\source) edge (O);
%
%    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
    \node[annot,left of=hl,xshift=-2.5cm] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```

Comment: If anyone bother to look at the lower right corner of this webpage, s/he will find **`user contributions licensed under cc by-sa`**. The keyword **`by`** means you should, at least, callout the name of the original author or, at the very least, give a link. Whoever not willing to follow the website policy is considered not welcomed.

Comment: @jsbibra Sorry, but many of my answers are original code wrote entirely for specific questions. Please stop denouncing other people!

Comment: attribution has been added

Comment: @JeT now that an attribution has been added, don't you think you should perhaps remove your comment? It doesn't look fair to complain about a missing attribution by linking to an answer which didn't attribute the original author either.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer just deleted !